# 3-OCC-MAX SAT np-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, 3-sat

Assuming 3-OCC-MAX SAT is the language of all CNF formulas in which every variable appears in at most 3 clauses. Is this problem NP-Complete? I'm trying to find a karp reduction between SAT and this problem, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Look for a gadget that allows you to "copy" a variable.

Comment: Which direction causes you trouble?